# Update items quantity in shopping cart in MongoDB (MERN Stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function to add items to the shopping cart. Inside the function I have an *if-else case*. **If** the cart does not exist for that given user then it is created from scratch, otherwise (**else case**) if the cart already exists for that given user, then the key quantity must be updated to the specific itemId of that given item with the same Id.
In the function there is already the code block of the if case in case the cart does not exist. What can I do if I need to update the quantity of the Items?

> Cart Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const idValidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 

const cartItemSchema = new Schema ({
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    itemId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Meal' }
});

const cartSchema = new Schema ({
    cartItems : [
        cartItemSchema
    ], 
    customer: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, unique: true, ref: 'User',}
});


cartSchema.plugin(idValidator);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

> Function

```
const addToCartByUserId = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.params.uid;

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next(
            new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, check your data.', 422)
        );
    }


    /* Find user in Database */
    let user;
    try {
        user = await User.findById(userId);
    } catch(err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Creating cart failed, try again later.', 500);
        return next(error); 
    }

    if (!user) {
        const error = new HttpError('Could not find user for provided id.', 404);
        return next(error);
    }


    /* getCartByUserId */
    let cart;
    try {
        cart = await Cart.find({ customer: userId });
    } catch(err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong, could not find an user by its id.', 500);
        return next(error); 
    }
    
    // if cart doesn't exists. It works
    if (!cart || cart.length === 0) {
        const { cartItems } = req.body;

        const createdCart = new Cart ({
            cartItems,
            customer: userId
        });

        try {
            const session = await mongoose.startSession();
            await session.withTransaction(async () => {
                createdCart.save({ session });
            });
            session.endSession();
        } catch(err) {
            const error = new HttpError(
                'Creating cart failed, please try again.',
                500
            );
            console.log(err);
            return next(error);
        }

        res.status(201).json({ cart: createdCart });
    } else { // if cart already exists
        let quantityToInsert = cart.cartItems[cartItems.itemId].quantity + cartItems.quantity;
        
        cart.cartItems.push({
            quantity: quantityToInsert 
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: So... what about your current code is not exactly working? The amount doesn't actually get updated? I thiiiiink you might be just missing `await cart.save()` from the end? And also the datatype of what your pushing... looks like a number? But shouldn't that be an object instead; the cartitem instead of a number?

Comment: The error returned is: 
```
let quantityToInsert = cart.cartItems[cartItems.itemId].quantity + cartItems.quantity;
                                                                                     
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')
```  
About *[cartItems.itemId]*. 
I want update the quantity value of cartItems array, that is into the Schema of the Cart. 
What I ask is how can I update the value and if I need to change only the cartItems.quantity value or the whole object, then in full {"quantity": 4, "itemId": "6163053d27d3afeb0dbad01a"}

Comment: Hmm, how I would start with this is `console.log(cart.cartItems)` - it's not an array in the way that you might think it is. You will need to do something like `cart.cartItems = cart.cartItems.map(...)` to update the cartItems... If this was my project, I would actually just make separate update requests for the cartItems (starting by making the CartItems have a `ref` to the Cart that they belong to). This is quite a lot to code so I don't really have time to make an example for you :/